# Getting electron-preload to run async with Quasar Renderer - Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, electron, nodemailer, quasar-framework

My desktop only application can send SMTP emails from Quasar / Electron through Nodemailer. This actually works pretty well.

However, if there is an error produced by my script in `electron-preload.js`, my Quasar `.vue` page has already completed while the electron-preload script is still running. So after the emails send, if there is an error, I cannot catch it with the `.vue` (renderer) page that has already completed.

I've been Googling for a couple of days to see if there is a way to get the electron-preload to run async so that my `.vue` page will wait for the results before it finishes. I am not finding a solution.

My users save their SMTP email criteria in the database, so I need to send that as well as other information to the `electron-preload.js` so the emails can be generated properly and then sent off.

I've been playing with various ways to get the preload to send back my needed info... and I can get that done, but every time my `.vue` page completes first and I can't catch the error so I can display it to the user. I can see it on the console, but not when I want it.

It seems electron-preload doesn't really work asynchronously. I've found some examples but I'm having a hard time getting them to apply to my situation. I'd appreciate any help.

Here is my working code:

Renderer (`.vue`) file:

```
const res = await myAPI.sendTheEmail(
  this.attachButtonToggle,
  this.stringifiedemailSMTPLoginArray,
  this.stringifiedemailsSubjBodyArray,
  this.stringifiedemailSendToPeopleArray,
  this.theEventType,
  emailType,
)
console.log(' emailSetup.vue sendTheEmail res: ', res)
```

And this is the script in my `electron-preload.js`:

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('myAPI', {
  sendTheEmail: (
    numOfAttach,
    stringifiedEemailInfoArray,
    stringifiedemailDetailsArray,
    stringifiedEtheEmailArray,
    theEventType,
    emailType
  ) => {
    const result = transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log("there is an error but this works - ERROR " + error)
        return result
      } else {
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response)
        return result
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem related to the preload or even to Electron at all. You have a function which works with a callback, but you need a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

If you use Nodemailer >= [`v1.9.0`](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v190-2015-11-09), the [`sendMail`](https://nodemailer.com/usage/#sending-mail) function can be both synchronous and asynchronous, depending on whether you pass a callback:

> If `callback` argument is not set then the method returns a Promise  object. Nodemailer itself does not use Promises internally but it wraps the return into a Promise for convenience.

So you can just do:

```js
sendTheEmail: (
  numOfAttach,
  stringifiedEemailInfoArray,
  stringifiedemailDetailsArray,
  stringifiedEtheEmailArray,
  theEventType,
  emailType
) => {
  // I assume you build `mailOptions` before...
  return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
}
```

If you use Nodemailer < `v1.9.0`, or that for whatever reason you want to handle the response in preload, then you can wrap the function into a Promise yourself:

```js
sendTheEmail: (
  numOfAttach,
  stringifiedEemailInfoArray,
  stringifiedemailDetailsArray,
  stringifiedEtheEmailArray,
  theEventType,
  emailType
) => (
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    // I assume you build `mailOptions` before...

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log("there is an error but this works - ERROR " + error);
        reject(error); // Or `resolve` if you don't want an error to be thrown
      } else {
        console.log("Email sent: " + info.response);
        resolve(info.response);
      }
    });
  })
)
```